# Cucumber + Capybara Not Executing AJAX Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

My Cucumber + Capybara tests are currently not executing AJAX requests. The test log does NOT contain the AJAX [POST] request, which leads me to believe that the request is never sent. Does anyone know what the problem(s) could be and how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at your test log file.  You'll see if the request was made and if it failed at the server.